# Is it possible to write script to automatically install firefox plugin?

Tags: firefox, plugins

I wrote firefox extension and want to be able to install it to firefox using sh script, for example. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this way:

firefox -install-global-extension "C:\Temp\extension-file.xpi"

Answer (score 1):

Note that the -install-global-extension requires you to actually be able to install it globally (I.E., are root).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Installing_extensions has various places you can place an extension, including user writable ones to make it installed.

Answer (score 1):

place xpi in GUID named directory in "staging area".  I would be more specific but I think you would prefer to read about it.

Answer (score 0):

`firefox -install-global-extension "C:\Temp\extension-file.xpi"`

The above command cease to exist. Its no longer working with release of ff 3.5.

RIP -install-global-extension